# Error message: argument of type 'type' is not iterable

Tags: python, scope, typeerror

I am just starting with Python and I have a short question.

```
import sys

# Function creates a list [1,3,5..99]
def createlist():
    list = []
    for i in range(1, 100, 2):
        list.append(i)
    return(list)

# Function asks for an odd integer between 1..100
def numberinsert():
    n = int(input("Please enter an odd number between 1 and 100: "))
    if n in list:
        return(n)
    else:
        sys.exit("Number does not match requirements!")

def main():
    createlist()
    numberinsert()
```

It gives me this: `TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code works fine. Where's the error?

Comment: `list` is a type. So `if n in list` doesn't make sense. You have also called a local variable `list` in `createlist`. But that local variable is not visible in other functions.

Comment: @MayankPorwal, No it doesn't (`if n in list:`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named your list as list. List is an data type name (I mean its an keyword). list1 or another name solves that error. And I globalized your list1 variable. I am not sure that globalize part but if I was wrong please warn me. This is my first reply.

```
import sys

# Function creates a list [1,3,5..99]


def createlist():
    global list1
    list1 = []
    for i in range(1, 100, 2):
        list1.append(i)
    return list1


# Function asks for an odd integer between 1..100


def numberinsert():
    n = int(input("Please enter an odd number between 1 and 100: "))
    if n in list1:
        return n
    else:
        sys.exit("Number does not match requirements!")


def main():
    createlist()
    numberinsert()


main()
```

Comment: I think just globalizing works . No need for list1 or etc

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to access a local variable of function `createlist` from antother function `numberinsert` and it's not possible (local variables are accessible only in the scope they are defined).
I would recommend you to change your code as follows:

```
import sys

# Function creates a list [1,3,5..99]
def createlist():
    odd_list = []
    for i in range(1, 100, 2):
        odd_list.append(i)
    return(odd_list)

# Function asks for an odd integer between 1..100
def numberinsert():
    num_list = createlist()
    n = int(input("Please enter an odd number between 1 and 100: "))
    if n in num_list:
        return(n)
    else:
        sys.exit("Number does not match requirements!")

def main():
    numberinsert()
```

As a side note, try to avoid naming your variables with names of built-in functions (like `list`).

You can also write your code in a more compact way, using `range(1, 100, 2)` directly in your `numberinsert` function:

```
# Function asks for an odd integer between 1..100
def numberinsert():
    n = int(input("Please enter an odd number between 1 and 100: "))
    if n in range(1, 100, 2):
        return(n)
    else:
        sys.exit("Number does not match requirements!")

def main():
    numberinsert()
```